# Gnome 3.16 ignoring Xorg.d conf files

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-shell, mutter

Since the upgrade to Gnome 3.16, my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file is being ignored.

This file contains the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "card0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

It is necessary on my system to control brightness after sleep.

`/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper` is ignoring this configuration file. How do I configure gsd-backlight-helper to use the correct backlight device (/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight) instead of the faulty one (/sys/class/backlight/toshiba)?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The '/sys/class/backlight/toshiba' device works only until I suspend my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-settings-daemon-backlight-toshiba) solves the problem. It patches gnome-settings-daemon to prefer raw type backlight devices to platform ones.